# PHP: undefined index in $_FILES[]

Tags: php

I tried to create an upload script in PHP. I getting this error message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: file in path\upload\index.php on line 3
```

This is my form (pretty basic):

```
<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="file" id="fileUpload">
   <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submitt">
</form>
```

This is my (not working) upload script:

```
<?php
    $name       = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    if(isset($name)){
        if(!empty($name)){
            $location = '../data/';
            if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
                echo 'File uploaded successfully';
            }
        }
    }  else {
        echo 'You should select a file to upload !!';
    }
?>
```

This is my php.ini config:

```
; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads=On

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize=40M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads=20

; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size=50M
```

So what did I do wrong. I checked every previously asked question but didn't find an answer.

**EDIT 1:**

After checking out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef) and altering my code the problem still consists.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitt'])) {

        if (isset($_FILES['file']) && isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {

            $name       = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $temp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

            if(!empty($name)){
                $location = '../data/';
                if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
                    echo 'File uploaded successfully';
                }
            }  else {
                echo 'You should select a file to upload !!';
            }

        }
    }
?>
```

**EDIT 2:**

I found the problem: Replacing action `upload` with `upload/index.php` resolved the problem. I am using XAMPP on my local machine to test my code. This is an error due to an incorrect Apache config by XAMPP itself.

Answer (score 0):

In your 'upload' logic, you need to ensure that the form has been submitted before declaring the values. Otherwise, it's attempting to set variables with a value that does not yet exist;

```
<?php
    //ensures the form was submitted before declaring variable values
    if (isset($_POST['submitt']) {

        $name       = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $temp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        if(isset($name)){
            if(!empty($name)){
                $location = '../data/';
                if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
                    echo 'File uploaded successfully';
                }
            }
        }  else {
            echo 'You should select a file to upload !!';
        }
    }
?>
```

Secondly, Change your form code so that the 'action' is it self (in this case, we're leaving `action=""` as blank):

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="file" id="fileUpload">
   <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submitt">
</form>
```

Comment: I tried this but the code inside `if (isset($_POST['submitt'])` isn't executed. Now is the question why. Clearly I am submitting the data.

Comment: See my update regarding the form code and it's "action" parameter.

Comment: I tried your updated version and seems not to work. I checked my whole directory but I didn't find my upload. Without setting action to `upload` there will be no upload logic or am I wrong?

Comment: The "action" parameter tells the form where to submit to, not what action to perform (in the sense you understand it). There is not and "upload" instruction per-say. Apart from my suggestions, are there any error logs you can provide?

Comment: The only thing I could find was from earlier (before checking if `submitt` is set): `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file in path\upload\index.php on line 5`

Answer (score 0):

When user submit form and didn't pick file to upload your global variable (array) `$_FILES` won't have item `file`, hence you have this error, and you have to check if this key available, like this:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']) && isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
    // Now you have strict and robust code!
    $name       = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    // Rest of your code ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer might be more useful if you actually explain waht's going on, and why.

Comment: Thanks... I tried a cobination of your answer and @Adam A one

Comment: @Techassi I've added some explanation!)

Comment: @AdamA I've added some explanation!)

Comment: @Vladimir Kovpak Thanks a lot. I am actually not submitting the form without selecting a file.

Comment: @Techassi Probably you have some another use case... but the point is - if you submit form without file, you will have this error... and only `isset($_FILES['file'])` can prevent this error...